# How to Store Composite Object in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to store a composite object in MongoDB. The object gets stored properly in MongoDB but during fetching back the object from MongoDB I need to typecast the inner Object without typecasting if I tried to call a method of inner Object then it gives me an error.

```
"TypeError: this.square.calculateArea is not a function".
```

I cannot Typecast the inner Object since I don't know which object is stored.I don't need to typecast the outer object during fetching it. Is there a way using which I don't need to typecast the inner Object also. I am posting my code below please help. The page which I used for reference is https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4356#issuecomment-236367135

```
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/example');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

class Square {
  constructor(u) {
    this.sideA = u["sideA"];
    this.sideB = u["sideB"]
    this.sideC = u["sideC"];
    this.sideD = u["sideD"];
  }

  calculateArea() {
    return this.sideA * this.sideB * this.sideC * this.sideD;
  }

  toBSON() {
    return {
      sideA: this.sideA,
      sideB: this.sideB,
      sideC: this.sideC,
      sideD: this.sideD
    };
  }
}

class SquareSchema extends mongoose.SchemaType {
  cast(v) {
    return new Square(v);
  }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.Square = SquareSchema;


class Polygon {
  constructor(u) {
    this.sideA = u["sideA"];
    this.sideB = u["sideB"]
    this.square = u["square"];
  }

  calculateArea() {
    var t = this.square.calculateArea(); // This line gives error.
    var k = this.sideA * this.sideB;
    return [t, k];
  }

  toBSON() {
    return {
      sideA: this.sideA,
      sideB: this.sideB,
      square: this.square
    };
  }
}

class PolygonSchema extends mongoose.SchemaType {

  cast(v) {
    return new Polygon(v);
  }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.Polygon = PolygonSchema;

const schema = new Schema({
  test: {
    type:Polygon,
  },
  square:Square

  /*
    Tried both the above one and the below method to define schema
  */
  // test: {
  //   type:Polygon,
  //   square:Square
  // }
});

// creating a Model
const Mod = mongoose.model('Learning', schema);

// Retrieving Data from Mongoose
Mod.findOne({
  _id: "5a9111ad1303fb2bc89e2440"
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data["test"].calculateArea());// This works without TypeCasting

});


// Inserting into MongoDB
var sq = new Square({
  sideA:5,
  sideB:6,
  sideC:7,
  sideD:8
});

var newPolygonObject = new Mod();
newPolygonObject.test = {
  sideA: 15,
  sideB: 16,
  square: sq
};

newPolygonObject.save().then(doc => {
  console.log(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an instance of the nested class explicitly in the parent cast function.

here is my version of your example:

```
'use strict'

var assert = require('assert')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/example')
// mongoose.set('debug', true)

class Square {
  constructor (u) {
    this.sides = u.sides
  }

  calculateArea () {
    return this.sides ** 2
  }

  toBSON () {
    return {
      sides: this.sides
    }
  }
}

class SquareSchema extends mongoose.SchemaType {
  cast (v) {
    return new Square(v)
  }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.Square = SquareSchema

class Polygon {
  constructor (u) {
    this.sideA = u.sideA
    this.sideB = u.sideB
    this.square = u.square
  }

  calculateArea () {
    var t = this.square.calculateArea()
    var k = this.sideA * this.sideB
    return [t, k]
  }

  toBSON () {
    return {
      sideA: this.sideA,
      sideB: this.sideB,
      square: this.square
    }
  }
}

class PolygonSchema extends mongoose.SchemaType {
  cast (v) {
    let x = {
      sideA: v.sideA,
      sideB: v.sideB,
      square: new Square(v.square)
    }
    return new Polygon(x)
  }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.Polygon = PolygonSchema

const schema = new Schema({
  poly: Polygon
})

const Mod = mongoose.model('Learning', schema)

var sq = new Square({
  sides: 5
})

var instance = new Mod({
  poly: {
    sideA: 15,
    sideB: 16,
    square: sq
  }
})

async function run () {
  await Mod.remove({})
  let saved = await instance.save()
  console.log(saved)
  let found = await Mod.findOne({ _id: instance._id })
  console.log(found.poly.calculateArea())
}

run().catch(console.error)
```

and it's output:

```
{ _id: 5ac8b37a5b220e744e1c1346,
  poly: Polygon { sideA: 15, sideB: 16, square: Square { sides: 5 }},
  __v: 0 }
[ 25, 240 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in case of your solution, I need to typecast the square object in PolygonSchema in my real use case(Can't share since it is confidential so created a dummy use case). I have multiple classes and I don't know the object which is stored in that variable. When I am retrieving my Polygon object from MongoDB I don't need to typecast it and I can directly call its methods. Is such thing possible for inner objects also?

Comment: in typical mongoose Schemas you explicitly declare the type of the path, but in the case of these extended schemas, mongoose doesn't know what the type of the path should be. Let's continue the discussion in https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6174 so that any ideas we come up with can be applied to future updates to mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use discriminators (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) instead of custom schema types. If you don't know the type ahead of time, discriminators are the way to go. In general, you very rarely need to create a custom schema type.